# CSS animation autroscrolling text issue

Tags: html, css, loops, animation, autoscroll

I have a autoscrolling text, the problem is that the animation restart before the div is complete.

You can have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/2oLf47o9/2/

Here it is the animation part

```
-webkit-animation-name: move;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: up;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
```

I want to letters to scroll till the "Z" and restart again from the "A".
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

in this case you'd better use transform:translate instead of a margin-top, since the former applies to the bounding box of a target (#box), while the latter to the container size.

```
 @-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform:translateY(-100%);
    }
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2oLf47o9/4/)**

and version without "delays between iterations"

**[demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/2oLf47o9/16/)**

Comment: thank you it works great! Why there's a delay at the restart? Is there anything I can do to make the restart faster?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2oLf47o9/16/ I returned margin-top as an initial static value

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase the margin height that the animation expects to reach when it is 100% complete. In this case the CSS that sets that is:

```
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {  /* Start of the animation */
        margin-top: 100vh;
    }
    100% { /* End of the animation */
        margin-top: -100vh;
    }
}
```

So you just have to change the margin the 100% version of the animation expects to something higher(and with the way vh units work this means setting the value lower), -200vh worked nicely when I tested the example.

Changed code would be:

```
100% { /* End of the animation */
    margin-top: -200vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CallumErrington, that works nicey but what if I want the animation to end exactly when the last letter has passed the top of the browser? Is that doable in pure CSS?

Comment: @Federico Its just a matter with messing with the values of the animation. So if you do what @GL.awog said since that does seem a better way to do it and try `0% { transform:translateY(50%); } ` to get rid of the delay.